# Изменение стандартных расширений файлов на нижний регистр (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, расширения

Столкнулся с проблемой стандартных расширений файлов в верхнем регистре.
Пример:
Вместо файла "Новый текстовый документ.txt" создается "Новый текстовый документ.TXT" (расширение в верхнем регистре).
Такую проблему наблюдаю с .pptx, .txt, .exe, .docx, .pub .
Буду очень благодарен за помощь с решением проблемы.
P.S. Windows 10 1909.

Comment: Можете показать содержимое ветки реестра "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt" ?

Comment: Viktor Tomilov, спасибо за наводку. Проблему решил так: экспортирую .PPTX или .TXT, удаляю (с реестра) и потом с помощью импортирования добавляю в реестр но уже с нижним регистром.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо, [Viktor Tomilov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/242027/viktor-tomilov) за наводку. Решение моей проблемы таково:
1.В реестре Windows открыть HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
2.Найти формат, который в верхнем регистре (Например .TXT)
3.Экспортировать формат в файл (ПКМ по формату>Экспортировать) > сохранить где-то на диске
4.Удалить (ПКМ по формату>Удалить) формат, который в верхнем регистре (Например .TXT)
5.Импортировать (Файл>Импорт) файл из 3-го пункта
6.После успешного импорта вместо формата, который был в верхнем регистре (Например .TXT) станет формат в нижнем регистре (Например .txt).